# Truncates the link in the wrong way

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

Have next fun:

```
internal fun createRequestUrl(baseUrl: String, routePath: String): String {
    val baseUri = Uri.parse(baseUrl)
    return Uri.Builder()
            .scheme(baseUri.scheme ?: "https")
            .encodedAuthority(baseUri.authority ?: "")
            .appendEncodedPath(routePath)
            .build()
            .toString()
}
```

But the third condition in the test falls:

```
@Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun createRequestUrlTest() {
        assertThat(createRequestUrl("https://google.com", API_AUTHORIZATIONS),
                equalTo("https://google.com/api/mandarine/v1/authorizations"))
        assertThat(createRequestUrl("https://google.com/", API_AUTHORIZATIONS),
                equalTo("https://google.com/api/mandarine/v1/authorizations"))
        assertThat(createRequestUrl("https://google.com/myroute/", API_AUTHORIZATIONS),
            equalTo("https://google.com/myroute/api/mandarine/v1/authorizations"))
    }
```

it doesn't add a `myroute` after the `base url`

> Expected: "https://google.com/myroute/api/mandarine/v1/authorizations"
>
> but: was "https://google.com/api/mandarine/v1/authorizations"

I think that the problem is in this line, but the alternative can't find:

```
.appendEncodedPath(routePath)
```

Comment: where is "someapi" coming from

Comment: @TimCastelijns sorry,  i updated the question a bit. I expect that will come:  `"https://google.com/myroute/api/mandarine/v1/authorizations"` but get: `"https://google.com/api/mandarine/v1/authorizations"`

Comment: @TimCastelijns `myroute` clipped

Answer (score 0):

Modified my own function:

```
internal fun createRequestUrl(baseUrl: String, vararg routePaths: String): String {
    val baseUri = Uri.parse(baseUrl)
    val builder = Uri.Builder()
        .scheme(baseUri.scheme ?: "https")
        .encodedAuthority(baseUri.authority ?: "")
    routePaths.forEach { builder.appendEncodedPath(it) }
    return builder.build().toString()
}
```

now I can install as many string additions as I want